# query $or mongodb in php

Tags: php, mongodb

this is my syntaq to query

http://pastebin.com/q05EBSUJ

i got error for result

```
[Tue Nov 27 13:05:16 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'invalid operator: $or' in /var/www/
```

i try to googling, alot of say if its wrong in mongodb version.

so is my syntaq wrong? or my mongodb version wrong, my mongodb verison = 2.2.1?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have extra layer of depth for **$or** array.

Try:

```
$result = 
    $mo->find(array(
          "node" => "stream",
          "$or"  => array("user_id" => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                               "to" => $this->session->userdata('user_id'))
       ->limit(5)
       ->sort(array("time" => -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

@tpae its not work.

i have my own solution.

```
    $result = $mo->find(
      array('$or' => array(
        array(
          'node' => 'stream',
          'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
        ),
        array(
          'node' => 'stream',
          'to' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
        )
      )
    )
  )->sort(array('time' => -1))->limit(5);
```

and its work.

Comment: You can move "node" outside of the $or since it is the same between both clauses, a minor point but still one worth noteing

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
$result = $mo->find(
      array(
        'node' => 'stream',
         array('or' => array(
          'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
          'to' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
         )
      )
   )
 )->sort(array('time' => -1))->limit(5);
```

instead of

```
$result = $mo->find(
      array(
        'node' => 'stream',
         array('$or' => array(
          'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
          'to' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
         )
      )
   )
 )->sort(array('time' => -1))->limit(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example which uses the `$or` operator to select fields from embedded documents:

```
$collection->find([
    // $or (array)
    '$or' => [
        ['key 1' => 'value 1'], // (array)
        ['key 2' => 'value 2']  // (array)
    ]
]);
```

Try:

```
$result = $mo->find([
    // $or (array)
    '$or'   => [
        ['user_id'  => $this->session->userdata('user_id')], // (array)
        ['to'       => $this->session->userdata('user_id')]  // (array)
    ],
    'node'  => 'stream',
])->sort(['time' => -1])->limit(5);
```

[References](https://coderwall.com/p/aymsvw)

Comment: i just know, that the mongodb query in php can use tuple, like yours. ['user_id'  => $this->session->userdata('user_id')]. let me try